# Insertion sort algorithm c#

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting

I am trying to implement the Insertion sort in one of my programs. What I have been trying to create is a sorting program (in both ascending or descending order) However I have tried with algorithms such as quicksort and merge-sort, I am really new to c# and coding. The problem I am facing here is the fact that my files includes both a string of code, as well as a double/integer (example: 75.350, 74.430, Thursday, Friday) and since this algorithm is designed for integers. Is there a way to convert it please?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader sh1Open = new StreamReader("c:..\\Files\\SH1_Open.txt");
            string Sh1OpenString = sh1Open.ReadToEnd();


            int[] x = { Convert.ToInt32(Sh1OpenString) };
            int j;
            int temp;

            for (int i = 1; i < x.Length; i++)
            {
                j = i - 1;

                while (j >= 0 && x[j]>x[j+1])
                {
                    temp = x[j];
                    x[j] = x[j + 1];
                    x[j + 1] = temp;

                    j = j - 1;
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(x[i]);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you sort an integer 123 and a string "123". Which is "larger"?

Comment: This line is bogus: `int[] x = { Convert.ToInt32(Sh1OpenString) };` it returns a single string for the complete file in a one element int array.

Comment: You can convert everything to a string (using the ToString method) and then sort them all as strings

Comment: Did you do some basic debugging of your code? Did you try with say three integers?

Comment: thanks for the comments, my piece of work is asking me to sort the specific files in ascending and descending order, for the strings, it will be from A-Z or Z-A and for the integer 1..10 and 10 ... 1 etc. If that helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is probably using generic method with IComparable constraint.

```
T[] InsertionSort(T[] x) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < x.Length-1; i++)
    {
        int j = i+1;

        while (j>0)
        {
            if (x[j-1].CompareTo(x[j]) > 1)
            {
                T temp = x[j-1];
                x[j - 1] = x[j];
                x[j] = temp;

            }
            j--;
        }
    }

    return x;
}
```

or using algorithm from http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Insertion_sort

```
static void InsertSort(IComparable[] array)  
{  
    int i, j;  

    for (i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)  
    {  
        IComparable value = array[i];  
        j = i - 1;  
        while ((j >= 0) && (array[j].CompareTo(value) > 0))  
        {  
            array[j + 1] = array[j];  
            j=j-1;  
        }  
        array[j + 1] = value;  
    }  
}
```

Also, there is probably a bug in this line:

```
int[] x = { Convert.ToInt32(Sh1OpenString) };
```

because you're trying to convert whole file to one integer.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I haven't yet tried your code ( little busy, but I will ) I've realised that line of code is an error - what could I change it to? Or it is just worth changing all my code? :)

Comment: I'd rather used additional `IComparer<T>` parameter(`Comparer<T>.Default `if none are required.)  than restricted items to `IComparable` in the first code sample - that is how `Dictionaries` and other similar constructs work. And array of `IComparable` in the second sample will force you to apply a lot of boxing-unboxing with value types (You can `IComparable[] comp = new String[] {}`, but can not `IComparable[] comp = new Int[] {}`).

Comment: @Yrneh It depends on structure of your file. If your values are separated by commas, the easiest way is calling `Sh1OpenString.Split(new char[] { ',' });` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). Then you'll have to iterate on returned array and call `ToInt32` method on every element.

@EugenePodskal Yeah, you're right, especially about second example, but @Yrneh is new to C# and I didn't want to complicate things too much.

Answer (score 0):

Since in `C#` the comparison operators are defined for `string`s you could just replace all relevant `int` variables with `string` variables. The algorithm should run the same  (albeit a bit slower)